# How do I use REST $filter with a "Hyperlink or Picture" type column?

Tags: 2013, rest, filter, odata

The `$filter` method works perfectly on regular text columns, but I can't figure out how to use it with a "Hyperlink or Picture" type column. For example:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Sponsors')/items?$filter=substringof('/sites/example.aspx',Target_URL)
```

This query is meant to get all the items in the Sponsors list where Target_URL contains the given string. Target_URL is a "**Hyperlink or Picture**" type column. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

It is a limitation in SharePoint 2013 REST filter.

You need to use CAML query along with REST.

```
url: "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Sponsors')/getitems"
method: "POST",
body: "{ 'query' : {'__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' }, "ViewXml": "<View><Query><Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='URL'/><Value Type='URL'>url</Value></BeginsWith></Where></Query></View>" } }",
headers: {
    "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
    "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
}
```