# Filter Hyperlink field url using SharePoint REST API

Tags: rest, filter, hyperlink, query

I want to filter Hyperlink filed URL using REST API in SharePoint 2013.

My URL is like below is working fine

```
https://<siteurl>/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Pages')/items?$select=NavigateURL/Url
```

But the below is not working

```
https://<siteurl>/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Pages')/items?$select=NavigateURL/Url,Title&$expand=NavigateURL&$filter=NavigateURL/Url eq 'https://bing.com'
```

Please can any one help me on this to get the items with the url `https://www.bing.com`?

Answer (score 5):

This is the limitation of REST API Filter that it cannot filter the Hyperlink fields.

So whats the workaround?

You can use CAML with REST to achieve what you want.

The CAML query will be like:

```
<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='URL'/><Value Type='URL'>url</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>
```

For using REST API with CAML you can refer [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/146129/52649) post.

Comment: This is slightly misleading. The CAML will work ONLY if you are filtering on URL because that's the default value. It will not work if you try to filter on one of the URL field's properties such as Description. Sadly, this long-running deficiency in SharePoint means you cannot execute a lightweight, fast query against a workflow status field and only retrieve the ones that incomplete (indicating a stuck workflow).